# convert a number value to dollar-format to display in proper visible format

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

trying to do something like dollarFormat in javascript after deducting some value but not getting type like `$8,657.00`

as this is small task, i do not want to use any libraries for this, but i manged to use alert for a $ sign before the number but how to manage the amount and decimals when they increase and put in the right place where needed

Comment: Did you want a javascript solution or a ColdFusion solution? What did you try? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: CF has a function. `numberFormat(8657.00,'$_,_.00')` https://cfdocs.org/numberformat. But since this is a display formatting issue, I'd use the function of whatever language you're using for your display (ie you shouldn't return a formatted result, but format in your output).

Answer (score 1):

Use `toLocaleString` – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString

```js
const dollarFormat = (amount) => {
    return amount.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2
    })
}
 
console.log(dollarFormat(8657))
```

Comment: @JamesAMohler [looks like it's fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified that whether you want to achieve this in CF or JS so, following example assumes JS. You can convert the logic to CF, if required.

Following is the function to format a number using `REGEX`:

```js
function dollarFormat( amount, fractionDigits ) {
    if( isNaN( amount ) || isNaN( fractionDigits ) ) {
        throw 'Invalid arguments';
    }
    
    var splitResults = amount.toFixed( fractionDigits ).split( '.' ),
        integer = splitResults[ 0 ],
        fraction = splitResults[ 1 ] || '';
    return '$' + integer.replace( /([0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$1,' ) + ( fraction.length ? '.' + fraction : '' );
}

console.log( dollarFormat( 8657.00, 2 ) );
console.log( dollarFormat( 8657.00, 0 ) );
console.log( dollarFormat( 12234348657.00000, 4 ) );
console.log( dollarFormat( 8657.000000000, 4 ) );
```